# Spring Cloud Gateway and Consul - All service checks failing

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway infrastructure with multiple microservices and a gateway. I have enabled Consul for service discovery functionality. In the Consul console, I can see all the registered microservices without any issues, but the gateway is displayed with an error message saying "All service checks failing."

I suspect this is due to the fact that the gateway itself does not expose any services and solely handles incoming request routing. Is it expected to see this error, or am I misconfiguring something?